# Rundeck Copy File to Windows Server very slow

Tags: windows-server, winrm, rundeck

I'am trying to copy a 19mb exe file from my linux rundeck server to a windows server using the copy file job in rundeck. This Job needs 2 - 3 hours to copy that 19mb exe. 
I connect to the server with winrm. 
Copy from rundeck server to linux servers works fast.

[image: screenshot rundeck copy file job]

Windows Server Standard 2019

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you check the PyWinRM plugin [limitations](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#limitations), maybe 19 megabytes is too much to transfer (works well to transfer scripts for example), perhaps it's a good idea to create a command step that copies that file.